# Making a WPF application for Android MVVMCross

Tags: android, wpf, user-interface, mvvmcross

I have a WPF application and I want to have it on android systems. Is there any possible way to run beautiful rich graphical WPF applications on android? I heard about mvvmcross but I have no idea of possibility. I need to be sure to make any effort on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there any possible way to run beautiful rich graphical WPF applications on android"
Basically: no, because WPF need the .NET framework.

What you can do is, if your WPF application is design in MVVM, to keep the Model and ViewModel code, and redesign the View Code to be compatible with Mono or any Framework running on Android.

This is for example what allow [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/?_bt=44014802708&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=Cj0KEQjwsJyfBRC729Oy5Pf26ekBEiQAYtd9QV8HDBa9xA6jInm7gNOUeFUqigZ67CGob177OAQg3PwaAn0W8P8HAQ). It will easily Build your .NET code for Android or IOS as long as it is MVVM.

[MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) is a bit different, as it is built on top of other frameworks (including WPF and Mono for Android). In other words: you will have only one codebase for the différents platforms, but this code is not in WPF, it is in MVVMCross :)

Anyway, it will be possible only if your code is MVVM. Otherwise it will probably be faster to code it again on Android depending on the application.